# Javascript code: how does it work?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

I recently completed the DevTools ~> http://discover-devtools.codeschool.com/ course and while inspecting the code used I came across some sections which I did not understand:

```
String.prototype.repeat = function (num) {
  return new Array(num + 1).join(this);
};
```

used in the `displayDate()` method thus:

```
var body = $('body')[0].outerHTML.repeat(10000);
```

What is the importance of using this code?

Secondly, within `displayToday()` method, `displayDate()` method is called with an argument although it is not defined to take an arg. Why is this so?

I am learning JS and couldn't npt wrap my head around these. Any help is welcome.

Comment: Could you paste the code or the exact URL for `displayToday()` and `displayDate()`?

Comment: Full code here http://jsfiddle.net/gabeno/3wbcB/ lines 2, 54 and 61

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
String.prototype.repeat = function (num) {
  return new Array(num + 1).join(this);
};
```

This code creates an array that is `num+1` in length, filled with `undefined`. It is then collapsed into a string using `join`, separating each undefined value with the context `this` which is the `outerHTML` string. When an array is joined into a string, `undefined` values are just nothing, thus the string generated only contains your separators which appear `num` times, thereby "repeating" the string.

```
//let . be "undefined, which when turned into a string, is just nothing
[u,u,u,...,u].join('test');
'(u)test(u)test(u)...(u)test'
'testtest...test'
```

As for the second question, functions in JS *will always* take in arguments, even if the function isn't meant to take one. Defining arguments in the function in JS is simply assigning the passed arguments a name. The arguments will always go to the function, and collected in a special array available in functions as the `arguments` variable.

```
function fn(){
  console.log(arguments); //['hello','world'];
}

foo('hello','world');
```

Comment: I have added link to the code: http://jsfiddle.net/gabeno/3wbcB/ I am trying to understand why use the repeat() function within the DOM. In what way does it change the DOM?

Comment: @gabeno it doesn't do anything in your code. Nothing it that function uses `body`.

Comment: thanks for the headsup, though I feel it could just be some sort of padding hack? Perhaps for positioning? Further going by your answer we need to reference `args` via the `arguments` array but from the code no reference to this array is made? Any tips?

Comment: @gabeno [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments) is provided by default in a function. It's directly accessible. Think of it as a pre-provided, invisible variable. Also, it's not a real array, but you can transform it into one.

Comment: Thanks @JosephTheDreamer you really can translate the codes!!

Comment: @gabeno I can read them but not know what they do. It's always better to run them.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass an argument to a function even if you don't have it listed in the declaration. You can access arguments passed with `arguments`

```
function foo () {
  console.log(arguments);
}

foo('bar'); // ['bar']
foo('bar','blerg'); // ['bar','blerg']
```

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple.

When you alter the `prototype` of something, in this case the default `String` class, you make that method available to any instance of that class, in this case to any string.

Now let's look at what the method does.

```
return new Array(num + 1).join(this);
```

Because of `String.prototype.displayDate = function(num) {`, the value of `this` inside that function is the value of the string. The `this` reference points to the current object, I guess that makes sense.

Then it's creating an array of num + 1 elements, which will all be initialised with `undefined`. `Array.prototype.join` returns the string representation of the array elements separated by the thing you provide as an argument to it.

in this case, you have an array of num +1 `undefined` values. the string representation of `undefined` is `""`, or the empty string. So you end up having num + 1 concatenations of the empty string + the value of `this`, or `num` times your string.

Say your string is "test", and you call `repeat(2)`.

It first created `a = new Array(undefined, undefined, undefined);`// 2 + 1 times.

Then it starts to join the strings, putting "test" in between each pair.

```
new String(undefined) + new String("test") + new String(undefined); + new String("test") + new String(undefined)
```

The above becomes:

```
"" + "test" + "" + "test" + "" = "testtest"// two times the original string.
```

Comment: Thanks @Alex23. I get the flow.